# How to use Controls from refrenced class library which uses own style.xaml file

Tags: uwp, user-controls, styles

So I build a **class library (universal windows)** to reuse all my controls in as much applications as possible.

I have written all of my controls an now I want to use them, but I when I use these Controls in my real application the Designer breaks and I can't build the application.

This is the error message : 
[image: Error message in german]

Which simply means that my style file can not be found.

So my solution is structured like this:

[image: Solution structure]

The style gets used in the sample control like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="/Styles/SampleStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And this totaly works but when I use the control in the mainpage like this

```
<Page
    x:Class="SandBoxSampleApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SandBoxSampleApp"
    xmlns:SampleControls="pack://application:,,,/SandBoxClassLibrary:component/Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:UsingSampleControls="using:SandBoxClassLibrary.Controls"
    >
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <UsingSampleControls:SampleUserControl/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The designer breaks and so on so I read a lot of article but it seems like i don't get it. Also InteliSense manages to Recognite the controls and so on even when I saw in the internet that I have to access the controls like this

```
xmlns:SampleControls="pack://application:,,,/SandBoxClassLibrary:component/Controls"
```

Here is my sample project: 
[SampleProject](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p11r0dfxoouzzxp/SandBoxProject.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document [UserControl usage scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#usercontrol-usage-scope),

> A UserControl element has a special situation for resource-lookup behavior because it has the inherent concepts of a definition scope and a usage scope. A UserControl that makes a XAML resource reference from its definition scope must be able to support the lookup of that resource within its own definition-scope lookup sequence—that is, it cannot access app resources. From a UserControl usage scope, a resource reference is treated as being within the lookup sequence towards its usage page root (just like any other resource reference made from an object in a loaded object tree) and can access app resources.

So you should put the **SampleStyle.xaml** in the same root position of the UserControl, that is to say the **SampleStyle.xaml** file should be put into your **Controls** folder.

Comment: I've read a lot of those how to pages but this was not what I understood from the text... But this totally worked! ^^

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and looking into this^^